# semi-consistently balance grouped items

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for an algorithm that allows me to roughly balance items that are grouped into groups with random sizes between `n` elements in a consistent manner.

Consider the following example:
There are `n` persons.
There are `x` hosts.
There are `y` customers.
A random amount `z` of hosts belong to each customer where `z` is `>= 1`.
Each person should be responsible for roughly the same amount of hosts without splitting the group of customers between the persons.
It is okay when a few customers swap around when more customers and/or hosts are added, but most should remain at the same person.

I know I can hash the host names and then modulo the number by `n` to get a consistent and roughly balanced mapping between `n` and `x` or `n` and `y`, but I do not know how to introduce the groups into this.

Any ideas?